# My checkbox in asp.net doesn't work with the codebehind file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, checkbox

I've got a checkbox, which should go to a method in the codebehind file.
This is my aspx code:

```
<input name="fullscreen_chbx" type="checkbox" id="fullscreen_chbx"  onclick="fullscreen_chbx_Click" runat="server"/>
```

And this is my codebehind code. The code should work but it doesn't even execute the method.

```
protected void fullscreen_chbx_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool fullscreen = false;


    if (fullscreen == false)
    {
        InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.F11);
    }
    else
    {
        InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.F11);


    }
```

There's always this error in the aspx file: runtime error in JavaScript: "fullscreen_chbx_Click" is undefined.
Why is there a error with javascript?

Comment: Your `fullscreen_chbx_Click` is being looked at as a JS function from the HTML. This is because you are not using a server side control.

Comment: That's not how it works. You cannot directly call back-end methods from JavaScript.

Comment: @MattRowland But I used runat="server". Doesn't it work?

Comment: The server doesn't understand what a HTML `<input>` control is. Check out @TimBJames answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using a ServerSide control, so the `onclick` event is attempting to fire off a JavaScript event.

You can change your code to use a ServerSide control, e.g.

```
<asp:CheckBox id="fullscreen_chbx" OnCheckedChanged="fullscreen_chbx_Click" runat="server"/>
```

Notice that there is no `onclick` event handler for the ServerSide control, so you will need to use `OnCheckedChanged`. You will also probably want to add `AutoPostBack="True"` to your control so that the event is triggered straight away.

```
<asp:CheckBox id="fullscreen_chbx" OnCheckedChanged="fullscreen_chbx_Click" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" />
```

Then this will trigger your server event. If you want to add a clientside event to this, then you can always add `OnClientClick="somefunction();"`

Comment: <asp:CheckBox id="fullscreen_chbx" OnClick="fullscreen_chbx_Click" runat="server"/> Thats my code now but it is still the same error

Comment: use `OnCheckedChanged`

Comment: asp:checkbox was right but i didn't included autopostback

Comment: yeah, maybe also because of that

Answer (score 1):

Change your code from to this

```
<input name="fullscreen_chbx" type="checkbox" id="fullscreen_chbx"  onclick="fullscreen_chbx_Click" runat="server"/>
```

to this

```
<asp:CheckBox id="fullscreen_chbx" OnClick="fullscreen_chbx_Click" runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your are using HTML control ans it is not server side control.

To use check box in server side you need to add below code.

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="fullscreen_chbx" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
oncheckedchanged="fullscreen_chbx_CheckedChanged" />

protected void fullscreen_chbx_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (fullscreen_chbx.Checked)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> AutoPostBack="True"

event of Checkbox control raises only if the AutoPostBack property of checkbox is specified with value "true".

Comment: You are not using asp control so it will not work you need to fire onclient click attribute to call javascript funtion